# Have any countries managed to consistently reduce government expenses as a share of GDP?

Tags: budget, gdp

In the US, government spending as a share of GDP has been consistently increasing for decades.

[image]

Have any countries managed to invert that trend and consistently reduce the share of government expenses over time?

Comment: A problem with this question is that there is no consistent definition of what government spending covers. For example a government could privatize their national system of pensions, and their share of GDP would reduce even though there's no money saved by anybody.

Comment: No, that is not really a problem.  I've seen GDP to govt spending stats fairly often - The Economist is fond of them, for example.  As long as one entity is doing the rating and is doing consistently and competently, one can compare across countries within that particular rating method.  Or, for this question, the same country at different times.  Only if you are trying to compare country X within rating framework A to country Y within rating framework B do you really have problems.

Comment: OCDE has some [nice charts here](https://data.oecd.org/gga/general-government-spending.htm) and I am pretty sure they know what they are doing.  From the looks of it, both Finland and Sweden would qualify, going from 60%+ in 1995 to a  "svelte" 57% in 2020.  Ireland too, from 37% to 27%

Comment: Does government spending include debt repayment? Because most European governments and America have doubled their national debts to keep corrupt banks running in 2007-2008 in billions and trillions of Dollars which means higher spending repaying the debts.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees yes, anything which consumes taxpayers money or ends up inflating the currency.

Answer (score 7):

The OECD data [here](https://data.oecd.org/gga/general-government-spending.htm) seems to indicate Ireland as a fairly big reducer. It probably helps a bit that Ireland spends very little on defense, but defense spending is not very high in most Western countries.

The spike in 2009-2010 must have been the financial crisis.  Ireland got whacked pretty hard as I remember but also recovered very quickly.

If you click around on it, Finland and Sweden, both near 60% in 1995 also went down, though they regained a good deal later.

[image]

Comment: Ireland might be a bit misleading due to them being used for tax evasion, which inflates their GDP artificially?

Comment: That seems like an odd statement on several levels.  First, I think the word you should be using is avoidance, not evasion.  Second, the choice of Ireland as a tax residence of businesses is precisely because of low corporate tax rates.  Third, almost by definition low government spending % imply low taxation rates.  I am not totally sure how Ireland would look if its neighbors weren't so uncompetitive tax-wise, but, in isolation, a government that seems to manage good living standards for its citizens and a low tax rate should be applauded by free marketers/small gov afficionados.

Comment: i.e. That's what competent right-of-center parties should be aiming for rather than immigration bugbears, coercive control of women's bodies and climate change denial.  Wake me up when we have such a party in Canada, for example.

Comment: [See this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprechaun_economics) for an explanation. My point is that Ireland's GDP value might be incorrect and thus OECD's statistics are misleading. And I agree that reducing government waste should be the main job of right-wing parties.

Comment: I am pretty sure Ireland was doing fairly well even before that 2015 Apple event that article alludes to so... meh.  On the other hand, while I am for low taxes and low spending, I really hope the various international groups can reach some reasonable accommodation to neuter corporate profit shifting shenanigans and start taxing more based on where the actual profits are being made.  Ireland may suffer from that but that is where the true leprechaun economics is happening, bizarre revenue shifting schemes.

Comment: Ireland's GDP is a rather dubious number because GDP is not a good measure of the true economic productivity of a tax haven, which Ireland is. The Irish government itself maintains an alternative measure to GDP for internal budget purposes in recognition of this distortion of the GDP figure.